# Java validation with nested loops

Tags: java, javascript

The program runs good but the nested do-while loop is not working. If you see the condition of the while you can see that it have to be a validation and if it is not in the range of those numbers it has to ask the questions again. You can see that the principal do- while has to validate that principal is not equal to 0 if it is it goes out from the program

I declare:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class ACMEMORTGAGE
{
   public static void main (String args [])

   {
       //Declare variables 
        double rate=0, monthlyPayments, numberMonthlyPayments, paymentAmount;
        int mortgageTerm, principal, years=0;

        Scanner key=new Scanner(System.in);

        DecimalFormat decimalPlaces=new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter principal amount (0 to end program):");
            principal=key.nextInt();

            do

            {
            System.out.print("Enter mortgage amortization (1, 2, 3, 5, 10.):");
            mortgageTerm=key.nextInt();

            if (mortgageTerm==1)
            {
                rate=0.035;
            }
            else if (mortgageTerm==2)
            {
                rate=0.039;
            }
            else if (mortgageTerm==3)
            {
               rate=0.044;
            }
            else if (mortgageTerm==5)
            {
               rate=0.05;
            }
             else if (mortgageTerm==10)
            {
                rate=0.060;  
            }


            } while (mortgageTerm==1 || mortgageTerm==2 || mortgageTerm==3 || mortgageTerm==5 || mortgageTerm==10);


            do
           {     
            System.out.print("Enter mortgage ammortization period (5, 10, 15, 20, 25):");
            years=key.nextInt();

           } while (years==5 && years==10 && years==15 && years==20 && years==25);               

       double i, n, x;

       i=rate/12;
       n=12*years;


       monthlyPayments= ((principal*(Math.pow(i+1, n)*(i))) / (Math.pow(i+1, n) - 1));
       System.out.print("Monthly payments amount:");    
       System.out.println(decimalPlaces.format(monthlyPayments));

     }while (principal!=0);

   }

}
```

Comment: You use `==` to compare. `=` is for assignment

Answer (score 3):

You are using the assignment operator  (`=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`) in each `if` and this is a mistake. While in C you might do it (and it usually an indication of a bug), in Java you have to use boolean expressions inside of an `if` clause. Should be:

```
if (years == 1)
```

And so on.

Comment: Also the while shows me another error call: "bad operand type for binary operator &&, first type int; second type int"

Comment: It's the same issue, use `==`, not `=`

Comment: I manage to the math that I'm doing and the program runs, but the validation of the loops don't. I'm trying that if the user don't put the allows numbers the question is ask againg.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (years=1)
```

Here you are assigning a value `1` to your `years`. So the result of the `expression` in your `if` is not a `boolean` expression.

Now, since Java expects the condition inside `if` to evaluate to a `boolean` value, so it gives incomaptible types.

You should use: -

```
if(years == 1)
```

Similarly, you need to change your `while` statement to: -

```
while (years==1 && years==2 && ...);
```

Comment: It isn't quite correct to say that `if(x=1)` is *equivalent* to `if(1)`, since the former also has the side effect of assignment. Of course, in this case it doesn't matter much since the compiler balks at it, but if the variable was a boolean, it would matter.

Comment: I manage to the math that I'm doing and the program runs, but the validation of the loops don't. I'm trying that if the user don't put the allows numbers the question is ask again.

Comment: @user1709115.. And if he enters the correct number, do you want to ask the question again, in this case also?

Comment: no, if he enters the numbers between 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 it moves to the next loop (that it is also not working the validation)